# How to publish a jsx file to npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx, npm-publish

I just want to publish a react component to npm, but found out it's so difficult. The file is simple, but with es6 syntax. what is the steps or solution to publish it to npm so that we can just install and run it with locally installed react? I have read this article http://chadly.net/2015/04/publishing-react-to-npm/, but it seems outdated and I failed by following it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use babel-cli to transpile the file to es5 and publish that file.

Put all your source-files in one folder, e.g. `src` and install [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) and add `build` entry to your [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) (package.json/scripts): `"build": "babel --out-dir=lib src"`.

No every time you call `npm run build`. The transpiled code will in the `lib` folder. In you `index.js` refer to this `lib` folder-folder.

Of course you can add `build` script to npm hooks such as `"prepublish": "npm run build"` or similar,

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a full Medium story because I had the same issue as you and there is no information about it. Check it out: https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce